# Find value in List(Of List(Of Integer))

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a `List(Of List(Of Integer))` called `selectedskills` with data that looks like this

```
(0)
   (0) 79
   (1) 1
(1)
   (0) 83
   (1) 3
(2)
   (0) 113
   (1) 4
```

and so on. How do I first, determine if the list contains say 83 and then second find the main index if it is found.   So in this case I want to find index 1 if 83 was found in the entire list.  Basically how do i see if any of the second level index 0's contains 83, then return the main index

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried?  We cant help with code we cant see

Comment: well i have tried selectedskills_(0).Contains(row("skill_id")), but I think that will just look at the main index 0

Comment: Am i going to have to loop through each of the main indexes to find the child index(0) that equals the value I am looking for?

Comment: Yes. The easiest approach is to use [nested loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement#nesting-loops) (by the way, in the example `Next indexA` and `Next indexB` can both be shorted to just `Next`).

Comment: Sorry, missed that you only wanted to check the first index (index 0) of the child lists. In that case you only need _one_ loop iterating the outer list, that checks each child list's item (0). Read up on the whole article I linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) as predicate for `FindIndex`:

```
Dim index = selectedskills.FindIndex(Function(innerList) innerList(0) = 83)
```

If no matching entry is found, -1 is returned as index. This code assumes that every element of `selectedskills` has an inner list with at least one element. If this is not the case, add checks

```
Dim index = selectedskills.FindIndex(Function(innerList) innerList IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
    innerList.Count > 0 AndAlso _
    innerList(0) = 83)
```

If the inner list has always 2 entries, you could also use [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples)

```
Dim selectedskills = New List(Of (Integer, Integer)) From { (79, 1), (83, 3), (113, 4) }

Dim index = selectedskills.FindIndex(Function(element) element.Item1 = 83)
```